# Why does import not work with React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm having trouble getting my app to recognize the `import` statement when trying to work with React. The documentation I'm reading says things like the following:

```
npm install react
import React from 'react'
```

Okay, so why is it that my app gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Here is the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
....
blah
....
```

something.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
....
other stuff
....
```

Error is thrown when this file is run. I feel like the documentation on React has taught me how to drive, but failed to mention that I need to put the key in to start the car.

What am I missing here? Please assume total ignorance. I'm a newb.

Comment: `import React from 'react'` is converted to something like `var React = require('react');`. `require` is a function is **node.js**, it does not exist in the browser. You also need a bundler to resolve the dependencies. You are probably better off using `create-react-app`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html

Comment: I'm putting this into an existing angular app, so starting from ```create-react-app``` isn't an option.

Comment: Then https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-an-existing-app.html

Comment: Yeah, I've read that. We're using gulp for our build process and I've done exactly what it says to do regarding ```.babelrc```, etc., and I still see the same error.

Comment: That's the *compiler* part in the docs. You need to solve/implement the *bundler* part.

Comment: What do you mean by the _bundler_ part? Isn't that what my gulp build process is doing?

Comment: The page I linked to speaks about three parts that make up a typical build pipeline : package manager, bundled and compiler. You seem to have taken care of the compiler part by configuring gulp to use Babel. Now you have to use a bundled to actually “bundle” all your modules together. The browser doesn’t know anything about modules. *”Isn’t that what my gulp build process is doing?”* depends on how you configure it. Apparently not, otherwise you wouldn’t get that error.